# Android List Preference one step behind

Tags: android, preferences, listpreference

I have a ListPreference in the preference system for my Android app to allow a user to select from one of up to 5 different accounts worth of data.  Inside the preference they need to be able to switch between the accounts they wish to currently use.  The problem though is that when I click on one of the selections, I get the selection from *before* the list was opened.  Code as follows:

```
    // Get the Account Preferences pointer
    final ListPreference accountPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("accountPref");
    CharSequence[] entries = { "Account 1", "Account 2", "Account 3", "Account 4", "Account 5" };
    CharSequence[] entryValues = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    accountPref.setEntries(entries);
    accountPref.setEntryValues(entryValues);
    accountPref.setDefaultValue("1");

    accountPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Log.i("theApp", "Selected = " + accountPref.getValue());
            return true;
        }

    });
```

So if I select the third entry in the dialog, the log returns "1".  If I then select the 5th one, it returns "3".  It seems to be returning the selection *before* the new selection.  How do I go about getting the *current* selection, not the last one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148952/how-to-get-selected-text-and-value-android-listpreference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If so, it's because you're reading `accountPref.getValue()`. The value has not been committed yet, it is only committed once `onPreferenceChange()` returns `true`. Instead, use the `newValue` parameter to read what the user has *just* picked.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was doing wrong.  It makes sense now that I stare at it more.  Thanks dmon, appreciate it!