# How to Get Selected Text and Value Android ListPreference

Tags: android, selected, listpreference

The XML file of my `ListPreference`

```
<ListPreference android:key="lpBirim" android:title="Birim"
        android:summary="" android:defaultValue="0"  android:persistent="false"/>
```

How to get the selected text and the selected value?

Answer (score 42):

in your PreferenceActivity do something like:

```
ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("lpBirim");
CharSequence currText = listPreference.getEntry();
String currValue = listPreference.getValue();
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use this snippet to get the value:

```
 SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
 sp.getString("lpBirim","-1")
```

Have look on the [tutorial](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html)

Comment: I get Selected value From this function **newValue** Field But How To Get Selected Text?
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object **newValue**)

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value)
{
    String textValue = value.toString();

    ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
    int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(textValue);

    CharSequence[] entries = listPreference.getEntries();

    if(index >= 0)
        Toast.makeText(preference.getContext(), entries[index], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    return true;
}
```

- index contains the index of the clicked item
- textValue is the Selected Value
- entries[index] is the Selected Text

Answer (score 3):

```
SharedPreferences Preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
 Preference.getString("your list preference key","-1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findPreference()` to get a `ListPreference` that has all methods you need. To have it working you need to use or extend `PreferenceFragment` first.