# How to get current default item in ListPreference

Tags: android, default-value, listpreference

So I know how to get the [currently selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787687) in a `ListPreference`.

I also know how to set which item will be [the default](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setDefaultValue%28java.lang.Object%29).

But I couldn't find the "reverse equivalent" of `ListPreference.setDefaultValue()`.

Is there a way to determine, at runtime, which is the current default `item`? (preferably its 0-based index in the `ListPreference`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String value = listPreference.getValue();
int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(value);
```

Comment: But that will give me the currently **selected** value, not the default one. Am I missing something?

Comment: But your approach works, so +1 and accepting. I think this works because the currently selected value automatically becomes the default value when the `ListPreference` is displayed next time.

Comment: When a ListPreference value is selected, it is saved in the defautSharedPreferences. The ListPreference will read this value when being loaded again. I read your phrase "current default item" and intepreted to be the item that would be checked when loading the ListPreference.