# Getting entryValue from ListPreference and set the changes

Tags: java, android, listpreference

I don't understand about getting `entryValue` from the `ListPreference`. I want to set localization to my app. But the code must be set before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. Simply, my app is a multi-language app. What should I do? And how to get an `entryValue` from `ListPreference`?

Here is my code:

**ListPreference**

```
<ListPreference android:key="pref.language"
            android:title="@string/language"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/select_language"
            android:entries="@array/pref_language_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_language_values"
            android:defaultValue="en_US"
            android:summary="%s" />
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="pref_language_entries">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Indonesian</item>
    <item>Russian</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="pref_language_values">
    <item>en_US</item>
    <item>in_ID</item>
    <item>ru_RU</item>
</string-array>
```

**As I know, this code is used to change the locale from an activity:**

```
Locale locale = new Locale("entryValue goes here");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Thanks for your effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why... This is pretty straight forward:

`listPref.getValue()` should get you the current selected entry value provided you've actually obtained the reference of the ListPreference from your PreferenceScreen.

[ListPreference documentation link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#getValue()).

[Link to a simple example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/listpreference-example/).

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148952/how-to-get-selected-text-and-value-android-listpreference) might also help.